# how can I invoke a subroutine reference generated from a string in perl?

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine

Several times in my code, I do the following.

1. generate a path from the name of a subroutine
2. invoke the subroutine and return a reference to what the subroutine created
3. store the reference to the path.

I want to replace these blocks with a function, on the
[DRY: Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
principle.
Thanks to
[Generating a subroutine reference from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236740/generating-a-subroutine-reference-from-a-string),
I know how to generate a ref to an arbitrary subroutine inside `dontrepeatyourself`
below.
But when I try to invoke the arbitrary subroutine, I get

```
Can't use string ("doggy") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Here is my code. `writeeverythingtwice` does the job but requires the user to type the sub name twice when invoking. What if the user fails to type the same name in both fields? Chaos and confusion and wasted time debugging.

Surely there is a way to invoke a subroutine inside `dontrepeatyourself`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
use feature 'say';

writeeverythingtwice(name=>'doggy',ref=>\&doggy,);
dontrepeatyourself(subname=>'doggy',);

sub dontrepeatyourself
{
    use Cwd 'abs_path'; use Storable;
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236740/generating-a-subroutine-reference-from-a-string
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    my$HOMEarg={@_};
    say ref \&{ $HOMEarg->{subname} };
    my $reftostore=\&{ $HOMEarg->{subname} }->(); # generates error
    my$path=abs_path('.') . '/' . $HOMEarg->{subname} . '.perlstorable' ;
    store($reftostore,$path);
    say 'we have stored to ',$path;
}

sub writeeverythingtwice
{
    use Cwd 'abs_path'; use Storable;
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236740/generating-a-subroutine-reference-from-a-string
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    my$HOMEarg={@_};
    my$path=abs_path('.') . '/' . $HOMEarg->{name} . '.perlstorable' ;
    my$reftostore=$HOMEarg->{ref}->();
    store($reftostore,$path);
    say 'we have stored to ',$path;
}

sub doggy
{
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    return [ 'foo','bar' ];
}
```

Comment: Something like this?  `my $reftostore; eval "\$reftostore = $HOMEarg->{subname}()";` Not quite sure what the goal is of this entire script, but that's beside the point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer, which requires an additional line of code, works as follows.

1. Generate the ref to the sub
2. save the ref to a new named variable
3. invoke the sub from the new named variable.

Thus we have

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
use feature 'say';

writeeverythingtwice(name=>'doggy',ref=>\&doggy,);
dontrepeatyourself(subname=>'doggy',);

sub dontrepeatyourself
{
    use Cwd 'abs_path'; use Storable;
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236740/generating-a-subroutine-reference-from-a-string
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    my$HOMEarg={@_};
    my $subref=\&{ $HOMEarg->{subname} };
    say $subref;
    #my $reftostore=\&{ $HOMEarg->{subname} }->(); # generates error
    my $reftostore=$subref->();
    my$path=abs_path('.') . '/' . $HOMEarg->{subname} . '.perlstorable' ;
    store($reftostore,$path);
    say 'we have stored to ',$path;
}

sub writeeverythingtwice
{
    use Cwd 'abs_path'; use Storable;
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236740/generating-a-subroutine-reference-from-a-string
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    my$HOMEarg={@_};
    my$path=abs_path('.') . '/' . $HOMEarg->{name} . '.perlstorable' ;
    my$reftostore=$HOMEarg->{ref}->();
    store($reftostore,$path);
    say 'we have stored to ',$path;
}

sub doggy
{
    my$whoiam= (caller(0))[3]; say 'you are now inside ',$whoiam;
    return [ 'foo','bar' ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```perl
my $ref = do {
   no strict qw( refs );
   \&$name
};

$ref->()
```

That said, `\&$name` is actually exempt from strictures, so you simply need

```perl
my $ref = \&$name;

$ref->()
```

---

What I might do:

```perl
my %dispatch =
   map { $_ => \&$_ } 
      qw( 
         doggy
         ...
      );
```

That allows you to perform some validation.

```perl
my $ref = $dispatch->{ $name }
   or die( "..." );

$ref->()
```

But that's probably unnecessary unless `doggy` comes from an external source.